# finding the sum of mod operations in a range

Tags: algorithm, math

if we have 2 numbers, say `a and b` then how can we find the value of `sum of b%i where i ranges from 1 to a`?
One way is to iterate through all values from 1 to a but is there any efficient method?
(better than O(n) ?)
E.g : if a = 4 and b = 5 then required ans = 5%1+5%2+5%3+5%4=4
Thanks.

Comment: It's sufficient to find a solution only for the case where a<b, since b%i = b for i > b so \sum_{i=b}^a = a(a-1)/2 - b(b-1)/2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For `i > b`, we have `b % i == b`, so that part of the sum is easily calculated in constant time (`(a-b)*b`, if `a >= b`, 0 otherwise).

The part for `i <= b` remains to be calculated (`i == b` gives 0, thus may be ignored). You can do that in O(sqrt(b)) steps,

- For `i <= sqrt(b)`, calculate `b % i` and add to sum
- For `i > sqrt(b)`, let `k = floor(b/i)`, then `b % i == b - k*i`, and `k < sqrt(b)`. So for `k = 1` to `ceiling(sqrt(b))-1`, let `hi = floor(b/k)` and `lo = floor(b/(k+1))`. There are `hi - lo` numbers `i` such that `k*i <= b < (k+1)*i`, the sum of `b % i` for them is `sum_{ lo < i <= hi } (b - k*i) = (hi - lo)*b - k*(hi-lo)*(hi+lo+1)/2`.

If `a <= sqrt(b)`, only the first bullet applies, stopping at `a`. If `sqrt(b) < a < b`, in the second bullet, run from `k = floor(b/a)` to `ceiling(sqrt(b))-1` and adjust the upper limit for the smallest `k` to `a`.

Overall complexity O(min(a,sqrt(b))).

Code (C):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

unsigned long long usqrt(unsigned long long n);
unsigned long long modSum(unsigned long long a, unsigned long long b);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    unsigned long long a, b;
    b = (argc > 1) ? strtoull(argv[argc-1],NULL,0) : 10000;
    a = (argc > 2) ? strtoull(argv[1],NULL,0) : b;
    printf("Sum of moduli %llu %% i for 1 <= i <= %llu: %llu\n",b,a,modSum(a,b));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

unsigned long long usqrt(unsigned long long n){
    unsigned long long r = (unsigned long long)sqrt(n);
    while(r*r > n) --r;
    while(r*(r+2) < n) ++r;
    return r;
}

unsigned long long modSum(unsigned long long a, unsigned long long b){
    if (a < 2 || b == 0){
        return 0;
    }
    unsigned long long sum = 0, i, l, u, r = usqrt(b);
    if (b < a){
        sum += (a-b)*b;
    }
    u = (a < r) ? a : r;
    for(i = 2; i <= u; ++i){
        sum += b%i;
    }
    if (r < a){
        u = (a < b) ? a : (b-1);
        i = b/u;
        l = b/(i+1);
        do{
            sum += (u-l)*b;
            sum -= i*(u-l)*(u+l+1)/2;
            ++i;
            u = l;
            l = b/(i+1);
        }while(u > r);
    }
    return sum;
}
```